# Magento enterprise edition upgrade

Tags: magento, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade magento enterprise edition from 1.11 to 1.12 using diff files. 
Im using patch commands like this "patch -p0 < name_of_diff_file.diff". But no luck. Can anyone help me.

Comment: this is a command you run in the root folder of magento via command line.  What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it would be easier to simply rsync your new files into your project then run the upgrade. The 1.11 -> 1.12 upgrade will take less than 5 minutes even with 50k orders